random forest accurancy=0
import os
import joblib
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, classification_report
from tqdm import tqdm
from PIL import Image
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

# Function to load the trained model
def load_trained_model(model_file_path):
    try:
        model = joblib.load(model_file_path)
        print(f"Model loaded from {model_file_path}")
        return model
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error loading model: {e}")
        return None

def extract_features(image_path):
    """
    Extracts features from a single image.

    Args:
        image_path (str): Path to the image file.

    Returns:
        A NumPy array containing the extracted features.
    """
    try:
        # Open the image using Pillow
        img = Image.open(image_path)

        # Convert the image to grayscale
        img = img.convert("L")

        # Resize the image
        img = img.resize((128, 128))

        # Convert the image to a NumPy array
        img_array = np.array(img)

        # Flatten the image array for clustering
        img_flat = img_array.flatten()  # Shape will be (16384,)

        # --- FEATURE EXTRACTION ---
        mean_intensity = img_array.mean()
        std_intensity = img_array.std()

        # Clustering
        kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2, random_state=0, n_init=10)
        kmeans.fit(img_flat.reshape(-1, 1))  # Reshape for KMeans
        cluster_centers = kmeans.cluster_centers_
        labels = kmeans.labels_  # Keep as a 1D array

        # Calculate std within each cluster using the flattened image
        cluster_0_std = img_flat[labels == 0].std() if np.any(labels == 0) else 0
        cluster_1_std = img_flat[labels == 1].std() if np.any(labels == 1) else 0

        # Assign cluster means
        cluster_0_mean = cluster_centers[0][0]
        cluster_1_mean = cluster_centers[1][0]

        features = np.array([mean_intensity, std_intensity, cluster_0_mean, cluster_1_mean, cluster_0_std, cluster_1_std])
        return features.reshape(1, -1)

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error processing image {image_path}: {e}")
        return None

# Function to load and preprocess image data from a directory
def load_image_data_from_directory(data_dir):
    data = []
    labels = []
    filenames = []
    label_mapping = {'normal': 0, 'cancer': 1, 'PCOS': 2, 'cyst': 3}

    for subfolder in tqdm(os.listdir(data_dir), desc="Processing subfolders"):
        subfolder_path = os.path.join(data_dir, subfolder)
        if os.path.isdir(subfolder_path):
            for filename in tqdm(os.listdir(subfolder_path), desc=f"Processing {subfolder}"):
                if filename.lower().endswith((".png", ".jpg", ".jpeg", ".tif", ".tiff", ".bmp")):
                    file_path = os.path.join(subfolder_path, filename)
                    features = extract_features(file_path)
                    if features is not None:
                        data.append(features)
                        filenames.append(filename)

                        # Extract label from filename
                        label_name = filename.split("_")[0]
                        if label_name == 'abnormal':
                            if 'cancer' in filename:
                                label_name = 'cancer'
                            elif 'PCOS' in filename:
                                label_name = 'PCOS'
                            elif 'cyst' in filename:
                                label_name = 'cyst'

                        labels.append(label_mapping.get(label_name, -1))

    if not data:
        print("No data found for processing. Check your data directory and file formats.")
        return None, None, None

    X = np.concatenate(data, axis=0)
    y = np.array(labels)

    print("Shape of X:", X.shape)
    print("Shape of y:", y.shape)

    return X, y, filenames

# Function to evaluate the model
def evaluate_model(model, X_new, y_new=None):
    y_pred = model.predict(X_new)
    if y_new is not None:
        accuracy = accuracy_score(y_new, y_pred)
        report = classification_report(y_new, y_pred)
        print(f"Accuracy: {accuracy}")
        print("Classification Report:\n", report)
    else:
        print("No true labels provided for evaluation.")
    return y_pred

# Function to save predictions to an Excel file
def save_predictions_to_excel(predictions, filenames, y_true, output_dir, output_file_name="test_predictions.xlsx"):
    df = pd.DataFrame({
        'Filename': filenames,
        'Prediction': predictions,
        'True Label': y_true
    })

    label_mapping = {0: 'normal', 1: 'cancer', 2: 'PCOS', 3: 'cyst', -1: 'unknown'}
    df['Prediction'] = df['Prediction'].map(label_mapping)
    df['True Label'] = df['True Label'].map(label_mapping)

    if y_true is not None:
        accuracy = accuracy_score(y_true, predictions)
        accuracy_df = pd.DataFrame({'Metric': ['Accuracy'], 'Value': [accuracy]})
    else:
        accuracy_df = pd.DataFrame()

    output_path = os.path.join(output_dir, output_file_name)
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(output_path, engine='xlsxwriter')
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Predictions', index=False)
    accuracy_df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Accuracy', index=False)
    writer.close()
    print(f"Predictions saved to {output_path}")

# Main function
def main():
    model_path = "C:\\OVARIAN DISEASES(LATEST)\\OVARIAN DISEASES\\RANDOM_FOREST\\random_forest_model.joblib"
    test_data_dir_relative = os.path.join("OVARIAN DISEASES", "Segmented_Datasets", "Test")
    output_dir_relative = "OVARIAN DISEASES"

    current_dir = os.getcwd()
    test_data_dir = os.path.join(current_dir, test_data_dir_relative)
    output_dir = os.path.join(current_dir, output_dir_relative)

    os.makedirs(output_dir, exist_ok=True)

    model = load_trained_model(model_path)
    if model is None:
        print("Error loading the model. Exiting.")
        return

    X_new, y_new, filenames = load_image_data_from_directory(test_data_dir)
    if X_new is None:
        print("Error loading new test data. Exiting.")
        return

    predictions = evaluate_model(model, X_new, y_new)
    save_predictions_to_excel(predictions, filenames, y_new, output_dir)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

the output:
Model loaded from C:\OVARIAN DISEASES(LATEST)\OVARIAN DISEASES\RANDOM_FOREST\random_forest_model.joblib
Processing subfolders:   0%|          | 0/2 [00:00<?, ?it/s]Error processing image C:\OVARIAN DISEASES(LATEST)\OVARIAN DISEASES\Segmented_Datasets\Test\Cluster_1_Normal\Normal2288.jpeg: cannot identify image file 'C:\\OVARIAN DISEASES(LATEST)\\OVARIAN DISEASES\\Segmented_Datasets\\Test\\Cluster_1_Normal\\Normal2288.jpeg'
Processing Cluster_1_Normal: 100%|██████████| 457/457 [00:20<00:00, 22.12it/s]
Processing Cluster_2_Abnormal: 100%|██████████| 467/467 [00:22<00:00, 20.36it/s]
Processing subfolders: 100%|██████████| 2/2 [00:43<00:00, 21.80s/it]
c:\Users\batri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\_classification.py:1531: UndefinedMetricWarning: Precision is ill-defined and being set to 0.0 in labels with no predicted samples. Use `zero_division` parameter to control this behavior.
  _warn_prf(average, modifier, f"{metric.capitalize()} is", len(result))
c:\Users\batri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\_classification.py:1531: UndefinedMetricWarning: Recall is ill-defined and being set to 0.0 in labels with no true samples. Use `zero_division` parameter to control this behavior.
  _warn_prf(average, modifier, f"{metric.capitalize()} is", len(result))
c:\Users\batri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\_classification.py:1531: UndefinedMetricWarning: Precision is ill-defined and being set to 0.0 in labels with no predicted samples. Use `zero_division` parameter to control this behavior.
  _warn_prf(average, modifier, f"{metric.capitalize()} is", len(result))
c:\Users\batri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\_classification.py:1531: UndefinedMetricWarning: Recall is ill-defined and being set to 0.0 in labels with no true samples. Use `zero_division` parameter to control this behavior.
  _warn_prf(average, modifier, f"{metric.capitalize()} is", len(result))
c:\Users\batri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\_classification.py:1531: UndefinedMetricWarning: Precision is ill-defined and being set to 0.0 in labels with no predicted samples. Use `zero_division` parameter to control this behavior.
  _warn_prf(average, modifier, f"{metric.capitalize()} is", len(result))
c:\Users\batri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\_classification.py:1531: UndefinedMetricWarning: Recall is ill-defined and being set to 0.0 in labels with no true samples. Use `zero_division` parameter to control this behavior.
  _warn_prf(average, modifier, f"{metric.capitalize()} is", len(result))
Shape of X: (923, 6)
Shape of y: (923,)
Accuracy: 0.0
Classification Report:
               precision    recall  f1-score   support

          -1       0.00      0.00      0.00     923.0
           1       0.00      0.00      0.00       0.0

    accuracy                           0.00     923.0
   macro avg       0.00      0.00      0.00     923.0
weighted avg       0.00      0.00      0.00     923.0

Predictions saved to C:\OVARIAN DISEASES(LATEST)\OVARIAN DISEASES\test_predictions.xlsx

